# SAP HANA revision control - tag all current objects

Tags: version-control, hana, revision

In the SAP HANA Design Studio you can see the history of objects.

[image: History view of objects]

**How do I tag all active (current) objects?**

Any lead on documentation for revision / version control would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be no full-scale revision-control-system integrated in SAP HANA you can export "Catalog Objects" and/or "Delivery Units (DU).

Exported DUs are archives and may be committed in the version-control-system of your choice. Catalog Objects are exported as file/folder structure and may be committed.

To Export go to the "SAP HANA Development" perspective in the "SAP HANA Studio". Then choose

1. "Export..."
2. choose the type "Delivery Unit" or "Catalog Objects"
3. chose the Objects or DU to export

[image: SAP HANA Development perspective in the SAP HANA Studio]
[image: Export Dialog - choose export-type]
[image: Export Dialog - choose objects to be exported]